# How do I return values from a previous Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

How do I return values from a previous Activity?

In the first screen, I have a text field called `TXTNIP`. But on another screen I have a text field called `TXTNIP` too.

Both are in different layouts. I want to get the text from the first `TXTNIP` and put it on the second `TXTNIP`.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
) , specifically `putExtras()` and `getExtras()`.

Here is a rough example of what you should do.

```
String value;

Intent i = new Intent(currentActivityName.this, nextActivityName.class);
i.putExtras("tag", value);
startActivity(i);
```

And then in the new activity, you would retrieve it like this.

```
String x = getIntent.getExtras("tag");
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this should do the job:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class)
mIntent.putExtra("key", "value");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

getting the data from the intent:

```
mString String = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

Comment: Gotta but it show my an error when i put it, look
Intent mIntent = new Intent();
mIntent.putExtra("key", true);
startActivity(mIntent, MyMenu.class); it say is the activity is not aplicable for arguments and underline the word "startActivity

Comment: i updated the code. i had some typos in it.. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You pass additional data to another activity via the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). see different Intent.put methods.